# Issue with YARP and Kubernetes Deployment: BFF Application unable to redirect to Identity Server login page via Reverse Proxy

Tags: .net, duende-identity-server, duende

I have set up an Identity Server and BFF (Backend for Frontend) application within the same Kubernetes pod, utilizing multiple containers.

The problem I am facing is that when I access the "bff/login" endpoint, the BFF application should redirect me to the Identity Server login page via the YARP reverse proxy. This redirection works perfectly on my local development environment, but after deploying the application to Kubernetes, it no longer functions as expected. The BFF application does not navigate to the Identity Server, nor does it redirect to the specified URL provided in the authority.

In Kubernetes there is a reverse proxy called trefik as in kubernetes you need a reverse proxy to work.

Could anyone help me troubleshoot this issue so BFF application can successfully redirect to the Identity Server login page?

I have tried deploying each application in seprate pod and in same pod as different containers

Here is my Ingress Route

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  namespace: myapp-dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'traefik'
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: 'letsencrypt-production'
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.myapp.com
    secretName: dev.myapp.com-tls-secret
  
  rules:
  - host: dev.myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp
            port:
              number: 8
```